# Parse.com migration to Compose.io

Tags: parse-platform, compose-db

I am currently migrating away from Parse to Compose.io, however the credentials listed produce the error, No reachable servers when I attempt to migrate:

mongodb://`<user>`:`<password>`@aws-us-east-1-portal.11.dblayer.com:27861/`<dbName>`

I have setup a database and user - I am currently on a 30 day trial

Comment: Contact Compose's support.

Comment: Compose.io isn't compatible with Parse Server; the answer from support was that their service offers scalable mongo to 95% of peoples use cases; but since Parse requires some special keys (failIndexKeyTooLong) it isn't compatible.